# Read all lines from BufferedReader before continuing

Tags: android, bufferedreader, stringbuilder

I am having a bit of an issue with my app. I receive a data through a socket, via a `BufferedReader`.  I loop round with `while ((sLine = reader.readLine ()) != null)` and append the sLine to a StringBuilder object. I also spend a new line \n to the builder.

The plan is that once the builder is all finished, `String sTotal = builder.toString()`is called and a total is passed to the next routine.

However, the next routine is instead being called once for each line rather than with the string as a whole.  The routine call is outside the loop above so I really don't know why!

Hope someone can help...

Edit: Code extract below.

```
public void run() {
    try {
        oServerSocket = new ServerSocket(iPort);

        while ((!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) && (!bStopThread)) {
            try {
                oSocket = oServerSocket.accept();
                this.brInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.oSocket.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder sbReadTotal = new StringBuilder();
                String sReadXML = "";
                while ((sReadXML = brInput.readLine()) != null) {
                    sbReadTotal.append("\n");
                    sbReadTotal.append(sReadXML);
                }
                sReadXML = sbReadTotal.toString();
                Log.d("XMLDATA", sReadXML);
                processXML(sReadXML);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        /* Nothing Yet */
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is really unclear - what do you mean by "the next routine"? Another method? What does that method do? It would be *much* simpler if you'd post some code.

Comment: Can you post a more complete subset of your code?

Comment: @ChaseMedallion & Jon - Code added :)

Comment: If you're exiting your internal `while` loop, it means you reached the end of your input stream (that's when `readLine()` returns `null`). Who's the client socket? Are you sure it's not establishing a separate connection for each line it sends?

Comment: @paf you are spot on. it was sending multiple connections. if you submit this as an answer I will accept it. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're exiting your internal `while` loop, it means you reached the end of your input stream (that's when `readLine()` returns `null` [according to the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29)).

You should be looking into the client, and not the server. What's establishing the client socket? Are you sure it's not establishing a separate connection for each line it sends?